# How to execute R script along with Azure Data Factory?

Tags: r, azure, azure-data-factory

Being novice to ADF, just wandoring whether we can set up the R script execution with the help of Azure Data Factory?

Any useful link to the information would be so much appriciated. :)

Thanks,
Abhijeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `ADF custom activity` to execute the `R` scripts in `Azure Batch Service` or on an `Azure HDInsight cluster` with `R` installed.

Links [here](https://dataninjago.com/2018/07/20/execute-r-scripts-from-azure-data-factory-v2-through-azure-batch-service/) & [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/RunRScriptUsingADFSample).

Comprehensive guide [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/data-factory-r-server-apache-spark-pipeline/) and [here](https://opdhsblobprod01.blob.core.windows.net/contents/4a6d75bb3af747de838e6ccc97c5d978/7fbd9eb738ab353b11a30ebc231daab2?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=QrEu23n3Zo%2FhTD5hQz7AZ9w2sy0E3jztujmR5001ins%3D&st=2018-09-04T07%3A31%3A42Z&se=2018-09-05T07%3A41%3A42Z&sp=r) for information on `Azure HDInsight linked services`.