# ADF: running an R script on Azure Data Factory

Tags: r, azure, azure-data-factory

Do you know a way to run an R script on adf and schedule an automatic email with blob attachments? thanks!

I tried using pools it didn't work
I've tried this solution from 2018 but didn't work with the current version: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52160348/how-to-execute-r-script-along-with-azure-data-factory)

Comment: You can call Databricks R Notebook from ADF?

Comment: 'run an R script on adf and schedule an automatic email with blob attachments', you want send the mail from ADF or from R code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to run an R script in a data factory job. And send an email using a data factory job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Databricks R Notebook here. Call the Notebook activity from ADF. If you have R code to send the email, then you can directly call it from ADF and send the mail.

If you don't have any R code to send the mail, use ADF and logic app to send the mail as a workaround.

Sample Notebook R code which returns JSON for the attachment.

```
query <- '{"start_relative": {
    "value": "4",
    "unit": "years"
  },
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "limit": 10000
    }
  ]}'
dbutils.notebook.exit(query)
```

Call this Notebook from ADF and it will execute like below.

[image]

Then use a web activity to call the logic app. Create a logic app with HTTP request and give the HTTP POST url to web activity. Give the below dynamic content as body.

`@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput`

[image]

**Logic app:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]